# Make a bootable image of a VirtualBox machine?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 18.04, usb, virtualbox

I have been building a Linux From Scratch (LFS) System for some time in VirtualBox and I’m ready to put it on a live USB. I want to save the system as a bootable image first, but I don’t know how to do that. I plan on using LFS on the USB as if it were installed on a hard drive with my regular swap, root, and normal storage partitions. If anyone knows a good way to do this, please share. I am using VirtualBox 5.2.26 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can dd a virtual machine image to USB

Here are some instructions that worked for me:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904557